# Using apply() family to repeate a plot() across columns

Tags: r, plot, indexing, apply

I would like to use the same `plot()` structure to generate several plots using y-values from different columns, with each column generating one plot.

I have tried this script:
`multi.plot <- apply(x = dat[,6:40], plot(dat[,i] ~ dat$elevation, xlim = c(2700,3500), ylab=names(dat)[i]))`

but I get the following error message: `Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`

I suspect that I am not indexing this correctly, but it seems like `apply()` is failing to recognize `plot()` as my function.

My questions are:
(1) How can I apply the `plot()` function in a way that `apply()` will recognize?
(2) How should I index the columns that I'm asking `apply()` to draw the y-values from?

Comment: The second argument to apply is a number.

Comment: Don't use `apply` for this use case but other siblings like `lapply` or `sapply`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are following an uncommen approach. However, this might work for you

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, 
                  y1 = rnorm(10), 
                  y2 = rnorm(10), 
                  y3 = rnorm(10))

apply(X = dat[, 2:4], MARGIN = 2, FUN = \(i) plot(x = dat$x, y = i))
```

To use `apply()`, we need to specify the `MARGIN` argument: `1` indicates iteration over rows, and `2` over columns. Also, we are asked to specify that `FUN` is a function of `i`: `\(i)`.

`lapply()` is one of several alternatives:

```
invisible(lapply(X = colnames(dat)[2:4], 
                 FUN = \(i) plot(x = dat$x, y = dat[, i], ylab = i)))
```

Where `invisble()` prevents us from having a cluttered console.
Notice. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family) for a comprehensive introduction to the `*apply()`-family.

As mentioned by @Parfait in a comment below, assigning the plots generated by `lapply()` as list to an object does three things: prints each plot to the *plot panel* of RStudio, prevents from a cluttered console, and potentially adds a variable to the current environment:

```
my_plot <- lapply(X = colnames(dat)[2:4], 
                 FUN = \(i) plot(x = dat$x, y = dat[, i], ylab = i))
```

Comment: Actually you can assign `<-` to lapply for list of plots!

Answer (score 0):

To get appropriate labels you could use the formula interface of `plot`.

```
> par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
> lapply(names(dat)[-1], \(x) plot(reformulate(names(dat)[1], x), dat)) |> invisible()
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(x = 1:10, y1 = c(0.831023408151727, -0.780900909187797, 
0.627744512621612, -1.39752583342895, -1.36603144884517, -0.426591927357527, 
-0.573874668897524, -1.12410812979077, -1.03177263449699, 1.62450406769964
), y2 = c(-0.301011564542263, -0.806952684601991, -1.10447371900453, 
-0.526551514943158, -0.948591544011062, 2.2674320631464, -0.567129921859871, 
-0.850873138812765, -2.08291288955887, 0.274955761306936), y3 = c(-0.122302384277575, 
-2.10908134396522, -0.353714724555026, -0.751037466477663, -0.205321986682473, 
0.25696789306013, 0.108042430306544, -2.34458076392015, -0.752990361065469, 
-0.458310883852258)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```